is there any helm chart for self hosted Novu on kubernetes cluster?
Deploying Novu on Self-Hosted Kubernetes: Best Practices for Helm vs Manual Manifests
Currently running:

$ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.31.2
Kustomize Version: v5.4.2
Server Version: v1.27.2

# Self-hosted cluster

What I'm trying to achieve
I need to deploy Novu (the open-source notification infrastructure) on my self-hosted Kubernetes cluster. I'm looking for guidance on the best approach - either using Helm charts or creating Kubernetes manifests manually.
What I've tried
First attempt was using kompose to convert the docker-compose file:
kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml

This didn't work well because:
No ConfigMaps were generated
Missing PV/PVC configurations
No Secrets management
Network policies weren't properly translated
Missing resource requirements and limits
What I need
I'm looking for:
A complete Helm chart configuration example textortext
A set of base manifests covering:
Deployments/StatefulSets for each Novu component
Required ConfigMaps
PV/PVC setup
Secrets management
Service configurations
Resource quotas and limits
Additional Context
This is for a production environment
Need proper separation of components
Must maintain scalability
Requires proper persistence setup for MongoDB and Redis
Need to handle environment variables securely
Questions

Is there an official Helm chart for Novu that I'm missing? If
creating manifests manually, what's the recommended structure for
separating components? What's the best practice for handling Novu's
environment variables in Kubernetes? How should I approach scaling
different components independently?

Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Environment Details
Platform: Self-hosted Kubernetes v1.26
Infrastructure: Bare metal
Storage:
  - UAT: Local storage class available
  - Production: NFS server separately setup and already has a storage class
Ingress: Nginx ingress controller


Stack Overflow is specifically for programming questions; if your question is "I'm trying to deploy this application without writing any code myself", another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be more appropriate.  Please review those sites' rules before asking: there's a specific call-out in the Stack Overflow rules that requests for external resources are considered off-topic here, and other sites may have similar rules.  (So it's okay to ask "how would I build a chart", especially if you have a specific technical question, but not "is there a third-party chart".)

thanks for the clarification i will edit my question
